# Ошибка flask Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... error при установке

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Установил `python-3.7.0a3-amd64`, при попытке установить flask (`C:\Windows\system32>py -3 -m install flask`) получаю ошибку:

```
Running setup.py install for markupsafe ... error
  Rolling back uninstall of MarkupSafe
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jaga\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 33: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jaga\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\jaga\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\jaga\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\jaga\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\jaga\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\jaga\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 33: invalid continuation byte
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема

Comment: А что такое `py`? Знаю про `python` и `pip`. И установка обычно идет как: `pip install flask`

Comment: @gil9red  - при установке pip install flask - происходит все тоже самое, py -3 -m install flask - так указано в учебнике, по которому учусь.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки покажите.

Comment: @ Sergey Gornostaev - добавил полный текст ошибки

Comment: С чем связано решение использовать альфа-версию python?

Comment: @ Sergey Gornostaev - собственно ни с чем, я начинающий, скачал с оф сайта самую свежую, поправте если что не так, буду благодарен...

Comment: @ Sergey Gornostaev снес и переустановил на 3.6.3 - результат тот же